# Javascript-Adding all files extentions

Tags: javascript, node.js, filenames

I want the code which i have here to search also by file name, the given situation is of course showing all the files ending in TXT in the folder and subfolders.
I would be happy to know the right command for it:

Thank you

```js
var path = require('path'), fs=require('fs');

function fromDir(startPath,filter){

    if (!fs.existsSync(startPath)){
        console.log("no dir ",startPath);
        return;
    }
    var files=fs.readdirSync(startPath);
    var found = false; 
    for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        var filename=path.join(startPath,files[i]);
        var stat = fs.lstatSync(filename);
        if (stat.isDirectory()){
            fromDir(filename,filter); 
        }
        else if (filename.indexOf(filter)>=0) {
            found = true; 
            console.log('-- your file was found: ',filename);
        };
    };
    if (!found) { 
        console.log("nope,sorry");
    }
};

fromDir('../yoyo','.txt');
```

Comment: If you need to search the "file name" you only need to change ".txt" with "filename" it works in the same way.

Comment: i wonder if i can do both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes to your code, I think it works as intended now:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

function fromDir(startPath, filename, ext) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(startPath)) {
        console.log('no dir ', startPath);
        return;
    }
    const files = fs.readdirSync(startPath);
    let found = files.find(file => {
        let thisFilename = path.join(startPath, file);
        let stat = fs.lstatSync(thisFilename);
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            fromDir(thisFilename, filename, ext);
        } else {
            if (path.extname(thisFilename) === ext && path.basename(thisFilename, ext) === filename) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    })
    if (found) {
        console.log('-- your file was found: ', found);
    }
}

fromDir('./', process.argv[3], process.argv[2]);
```

**UPDATE:** code changed to follow requirements changes.

Comment: I've updated the above proposed solution accordingly. That is, by typing `node find .ext filename` it will find all ocurrences of filename(basename).ext. For example, `node find .txt myfile`, it will find any file named `myfile.txt` in the current directory and in any subdirectories.